# Как вывести динамическую таблицу из БД?

Tags: java, база-данных, gui

Интересует как вывести динамическую таблицу из БД на GUI - форму. Использовал интерфейс "AbstractTableModel".

> ```
> public void ADDJ(DBConnection connect, String nametable)
> {
>     ResultSet resultSet = connect.query("SELECT * from " + nametable);// poluchaem stroki s tablici
>     list.clear();
>
>     try {
>         final int koll = resultSet.getMetaData().getColumnCount();
>
>         System.out.println("Column count = " + koll);
>         columnCount = koll;
>         for(int i=1; i<=koll; i++) {
>
>             ResultSetMetaData meta = resultSet.getMetaData();
>             String column = meta.getColumnName(i);
>             System.out.println("Column[" + i + "] = " + column);
>
>          // String [] row = {column, " ", " ", " ", " "};
>          //  addData(row);
>
>         }
>        while (resultSet.next())
>         {
>
>              for (int ii = 1; ii <= koll; ii++) {
>                   //row[ii - 1] = resultSet.getString(ii);
>                  String [] row = {resultSet.getString(1), resultSet.getString(2), resultSet.getString(3),
>                          resultSet.getString(4), resultSet.getString(5)};
>            // String[] row = {resultSet.getString(ii)};
>                   addData(row);
>               }
>             }
>
>     }
>     catch (SQLException e)
>     {
>         e.printStackTrace();
>     }
>
> }
> ```

Когда я пытаюсь обратится к индексу массива, что бы внести туда данные, начинает рушатся.

Comment: В качестве GUI FX или Swing? Я бы посоветовал всетаки взглянуть в сторону ORM т.к. например в FX таблицу можно настроить так, что ей можно напрямую скармливать результат запроса из таблицы, без какой-либо конвертации.

Comment: @Riĥard Brugekĥaim, Swing, Я бы с радостью попробовал сделать в чём-то другом, но я не обладаю достаточными навыками, только учу). Раз уж начал проект со Swing, то лучше для него. Или тяжело реализуется?

Comment: https://github.com/Tsyklop/Java-Swing/tree/Main/DBView Вот. Гляди.

Comment: @Tsyklop Спасибо, по вашему практически разобрался, я был довольно близок.)). Не мог понять откуда у вас список есть с переменной "Rows" - думал может библиотеку надос качать. Пока не увидел файл с реализацией.  Суть я понял, думаю справляюсь.